# "I saw him playing football"

Tags: ambiguity, syntactic-analysis, objects, present-participles, gerund-phrases

In this sentence, is "playing football" a participle phrase describing the object "him", or is "him playing football" all a gerund phrase functioning as the object?

The problem with English grammar is that too many different words share the same form. I find it difficult to distinguish gerunds and present participles.

Comment: It is ambiguous.

Comment: Why are you trying to “distinguish” these?

Comment: I'm trying to develop software that constructs a sentence, and it requires that everything fit into well defined classes. The biggest challenge turns out to be just understanding the grammar.

Comment: What you need to bake into your code is that verbs of perception can be followed by object + -ing form. How you name the phrase "playing football" is irrelevant imho.

Comment: How it's classified does make a difference, because participles and gerunds have different rules governing their use. A participle phrase can only be an adjective, but a gerund has more uses.  Also the structure of the sentence is different depending on what category it fits in.

Comment: If its a participle it's: sub. + verb. + obj. + adj.   If it's a gerund, it's simply sub + verb + obj  with no modifiers. It's seems like a trivial thing to fuss over but when you're trying to establish a base set of rules for constructing and/or interpreting all sentences, this ambiguity can cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

In "I saw him playing football" "playing" is traditionally considered a participle, at least grammars deal with this structure in the chapter participles.

But that is mere convention. You can consider "playing" a gerund as well.
I saw him (in the act of) playing football/I saw him (at) playing football.

There is only one way out of this dilemma of English. In some cases where it can't be determined unambigously whether an ing-form is a participle or a gerund to call it gp-form (gerund or participle).

Answer (score 0):

The *-ing form* of the verb, "playing" is not a *gerund*. But in the following example, it is:  "Playing football is fun". - "playing" is being used a noun (subject).

“him playing football” = gerund phrase functioning as the object of the verb "see".

(Edited to better address the question)

Comment: So you're saying that "playing football" is an elliptical adverb clause that's short for "while he was playing football" describing the verb saw?

Comment: No. I just tried to illustrate the function of a gerund, for your question appeared to have some confusion about it.

Comment: Why can't my example sentence use the gerund? "him playing football" can be interpreted as a gerund phrase functioning as the object of saw.

Comment: Here's what a 'gerund' is: the English -ing form of a verb when functioning as a noun, as writing in "Writing is easy".

Comment: "...For your question appeared to have some confusion about it."  Yes my question is about the phrase "playing football".  I thought there were only two possibilities: either a participle phrase describing the object "him" , or  a gerund functioning as the object with "him" as the subject of the gerund.  You said that it's neither, but rather a shortened form of the adverbial clause "while he was playing football" describing saw.

Comment: "Here's what a 'gerund' is: the English -ing form of a verb when functioning as a noun, as writing in "Writing is easy".  I'm aware of that. but why is "him playing football" not a gerund?

Comment: "him playing football" - these three words together cannot be a gerund. Let's see if "playing" is the gerund form of the verb "to play". Yes, but not here. It's ending with "-ing", but not serving as the subject of a verb.

Comment: A gerund phrase is a gerund and all of it's complements and modifiers. Why is "him playing football" not a gerund phrase?

Comment: Let's continue your statement: ... and acting as the subject. Well, then in the following, it can be a gerund phrase: "Playing on the beach is fun". "Playing on the beach" -- subject of the verb "to be". It's a phrase beginning with a gerund AND acting as the subject or object.

Comment: A gerund (phrase) can also be an object though, it does not have to be the subject.

Comment: Right! I just edited my answer.

Comment: Or, yes. Then in that case, "him playing football" can be the gerund phrase functioning as the object.